# iphone 5c could not be synced an unknown error occured (-4)

Tags: data-synchronization, error

Every time I try to synced music from my laptop to iPhone I get this message; I tried to reinstall Itunes I updated the iphone software, nothing works!!
I can't transfer any music on my Iphone from my computer !! This is insane

Answer (score 1):

- Launch iTunes, connect the device and uncheck Sync Music, Sync Movies, Sync TV Shows, and Sync Podcasts” in iTunes.
- Click Sync. This will remove all media from the device but keep it in iTunes.
- Disconnect the device from the computer.
- Switch off the iOS device by holding down the Sleep/Wake button and using the  Slide to Power Off button.
- Hold down the Sleep/Wake button to turn the device back on.
- Connect the device to the computer.
- Click on the device in iTunes and tick the media that you want to sync.
- Click Sync.